# Trying to use parentheses in a "psbarcode" adds a new line after the first right parenthesis + charset encoding error

Tags: pstricks, pst-barcode

I'm trying to use the `pst-barcode` package to create a vcard contained in a qrcode, and I was surprised to see that a vcard that was working with another programming language to generate my qrcode was not working with this package.

After investigation, it turns out that the problem was caused by `psbarcode`: after the **first** (and only the first!) use of left and right parentheses, a newline is created (instead of the first *space* after the right parenthesis).

(If it could help: I also found out that using a left parenthesis without the right one after just returned a blank qrcode)

Here is my current code:

```
\begin{pspicture}(25mm,25mm)
    \begingroup
        % The following def are used to solve a previous problem as
        % there were "penalty @M" added for this characters
        \def:{\string:}%
        \def;{\string;}%
        \psbarcode{%
MECARD:N:Doe,John;TEL:+1 (234) 567-8910;EMAIL:john@doe.com;;%
        }{eclevel=L width=1.161 height=1.161}{qrcode}
    \endgroup
\end{pspicture}
```

I know that we need, in general, to define a number without space and other characters in a vcard, but here I need it that way, and I think that it could be useful for other situations when we need to have parentheses in a vcard.

An other piece of information that could be useful: my current version of `pst-barcode` has this filedate : `\def\filedate{2011/03/10}`

**Note:** Using `^040` and `^041` instead of `(` and `)` and the `parse` option also solves the problem.

---

The new problem encountered after this correction is linked to the charset.
Here is the second barcode I have :

```
        \psbarcode{%
BEGIN:VCARD^^J%
N:Doé;John^^J%
TEL;WORK:+1 ^040234^041 567-8910^^J%
EMAIL:john@doe.com^^J%
END:VCARD%
}{eclevel=L width=1.161 height=1.161 parse}{qrcode}
```

It seems that the returned element is not readable by all barcode readers, but if I remove the accent, it works well. The reader was tested with others utf-8 encoded barcodes, and the returned value was correct.

I tried to use an UTF-8 BOM (`^239^187^191`) but it was not working.

Answer (score 2):

there are three possible ways to pass the data into the macro:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(1.2in,1.2in)
\psbarcode{MECARD:N:Doe,John;TEL:+1 (234) 567-8910;EMAIL:john@doe.com;;}%
        {eclevel=L width=1.161 height=1.161}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
%
\begin{pspicture}(1.2in,1.2in)
\psbarcode{MECARD\string:N\string:Doe,John\string;TEL:+1 (234) 567-8910\string;EMAIL\string:john@doe.com\string;\string;}%
        {eclevel=L width=1.161 height=1.161}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
%
\begin{pspicture}(1.2in,1.2in)%% using ASCII decimal values, eg ^058->:
\psbarcode{MECARD^058N^058Doe,John^059TEL:+1 (234) 567-8910^059EMAIL^058john@doe.com^059^059}%
        {eclevel=L width=1.161 height=1.161 parse}{qrcode}% option parse needed
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The data must be in one line! A % cannot be used as a TeX command character!

With this example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(1.2in,1.2in)
        \psbarcode{BEGIN:VCARD
        N:Do^233;John^010
        TEL;WORK:+1 ^040234^041 567-8910^010
        EMAIL:john@doe.com^010
        END:VCARD}
{eclevel=L width=1.161 height=1.161 parse}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

which i converted to a png image and uploaded it to http://zxing.org/w/decode I get:

```
BEGIN:VCARD N:Doé;John
 TEL;WORK:+1 (234) 567-8910
 EMAIL:john@doe.com
 END:VCARD
```

Comment: In fact the multiline is not a problem at all (for instance, using a vcard - multiline format - is working well, except for parenthesis). The only problem is due to parenthesis. But it's funny because your code is not working for me (same problem that I had) but seems ok for you... (EDIT: perhaps linked to the fact that I'm using pdflatex with auto-pst-pdf package?)
However, using the "parse" argument with `^040` and `^041` for the parenthesis, it seems to work ! (I have now an encoding problem, as I'm using some accents and I don't know why, but psbarcode don't want to compute them correctly)

Comment: sigh ... If you have problems with an accent, then show it in your question ...

Comment: The "charset problem" is now described in the question ! (Thanks for your help about the first part, Herbert !)

Comment: a newline is `^013^010` (CRLF) and é is `^233`. See http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859. And, as I already wrote, write the data in ONE line

Comment: For the newline, it does not seems to change anything. And about the `^233` : with `N:Doe;John` it's working, but without accent; with `N:Doé;John` and `N:Do^233;John` it's not working. `:(` (just to precise: I'm using the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` command) -- Exactly the same QRCode is output with the data in one line.

Comment: what happens if you use only `^010` for the newline?

Comment: It's the same thing ! (the QRCode change a little bit due to the fact that there is some characters less - the `^013` - but there is still the same problem)

Comment: the problem is that I cannot test the output. Is there an online scanner available where I can upload a png or gif?

Comment: The scanner that returns the error here is "flashcode by mobiletag" on iPhone. It seems to work on "QR Code Scanner" on Android, and on "Lynkee 2" on iPhone.
However, "flashcode by mobiletag" works with another QRCode that contains exactly the same thing, encoded in UTF-8, and generated by TCPDF.
Here are the two QR with identical content: from TCPDF (working: http://goo.gl/RRQkD) and from PST-Barcode (not working: http://goo.gl/HvCwx).
Using http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx we can see the difference in raw bytes that could explain the problem (using the goo.gl urls).

Comment: @XaF: see my edited answer

Comment: I tried your code (adding auto-pst-pdf) but it was not working either.
As you can see with the examples I found in my previous comment (http://goo.gl/gKwPN is the zxing.org result for TCPDF encoded QR and http://goo.gl/pCQKB is the result for PST-Barcode encoded QR), both are returning the good text (it seems) but with different raw bytes, and the PST-Barcode one isn't working with the flashcode application `:(`